# 'Where' function type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

For example, i've got following function:

```
foo :: t -> f
foo var = foo' b var
    where
        b = bar 0.5 vect
```

and I need to specify literals' 0.5 type — 't'

If i write smth. like `(0.5::t)`, GHC creates new type variable 't0', which is not corresponding to original 't'.

I've wrote a small function

```
ct :: v -> v -> v
ct _ u = u
```

and use it like this:

```
b = bar (ct var 0.5) d
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: There's a compiler option that will let you say `(0.5::t)` and it will match the `t` to the surrounding scope's `t`, but I forget what it is.

Comment: you wrote very little information - for example what is bar respectively bar's type signature and foo' as well. as i understand it lowercase letters are placeholders for ghc to be inferred. known types start with an uppercase letter like `Float` or `Int` so you pass almost no type information to the compiler which is asking for more information.

Comment: if you try to load the file with `ghci` the interpreter does it still fail - as i remember it is less strictly. in addition you can find out about a function's type by `:t foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ScopedTypeVariables` to bring the type variables from the top-level signature into scope,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foo :: forall t. Fractional t => t -> f
foo var = foo' b var
  where
    b = bar (0.5 :: t) vect
```

Your helper function `ct` is - with flipped arguments - already in the Prelude,

```
ct = flip asTypeOf
```

so

```
  where
    b = bar (0.5 `asTypeOf` var) vect
```

would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Without ScopedTypeVariables, the usual solution is to re-write `b` into a function such that it takes in type `t` and returns something containing type `t`. That way, its `t` is generic and independent of the outer `t` and can be inferred based on where it is used.

However, without knowing the types of your `foo'` and `bar`, etc., I cannot tell you what exactly it will look like